# How to move a text file using Oracle

Tags: oracle, file, plsql

I have two questions.

(1) how to make move text file from folder:

```
C:\Data\inbox\test.txt
```

to target Folder?

```
C:\Data\outbox\test.txt
```

(2)  how to make get list of directory files in Folder?

```
C:\Data\inbox\
```

Thank you...

Comment: You mean from inside Oracle with PSQL? These are fairly trivial to do from a shell obviously.

Comment: @Rup yes PLSQL, how to make ?

Answer (score 7):

Oracle provides a package of utilities for working with files, UTL_FILE.  Since 9i this has included [the FRENAME() procedure](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003641), which works like the unix `mv` command.  We can use it to rename the file and/or its directory.  Note that the Oracle os account must have read and write privileges on both directories.  Also this procedure uses [DIRECTORY objects](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm#i2061958), rather than explicit paths.

As for getting a list of files in a directory, there is no Oracle built-in.  One solution is to use a Java Stored Procedure.  Tom Kyte has an example of this.  [Find it here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).  There is another way of doing it since 11.1.0.7, which is to use an external table pre-processor file.  Adrian Billington wrote [a nice article on this](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513).  The executed file is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at UTL_FILE?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

Comment: UTL_FILE cannot get a list of files from a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Where you say:

> 2-) Question Two
>
> Folder: C:\Data\inbox\
>
> how to make get directory files list ?

Tom Kyte has a nice solution shown [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584)

Answer (score -1):

```
begin
  UTL_FILE.FCOPY (
   'EMPLOYEE'   , -- THIS IS A ORACLE DIRECTORY
   'EmpInfo.TXT'   , --FILE NAME
   'PROM_INCR'   , -- THIS IS A ORACLE DIRECTORY
   'EmpInfo.TXT' ); -- DESTINATION FILE
end;
```

try this