# Using pl/sql how do I locate a file in a directory and move the file?

Tags: oracle, file, plsql

Using pl/sql how do I locate a file in a directory and move the file?

Comment: Check the following link. I believe you will find your answer

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/FileHandlingFromPLSQL.php
Its quite old by the way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Move Txt File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529273/oracle-move-txt-file)

Answer (score 7):

To test if a file exists, you can use `UTL_FILE.fGetAttr`. [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_file.htm#i1003488)

For example:

```
DECLARE
  l_file_exists BOOLEAN;
  l_file_len    NUMBER;
  l_blocksize   BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  utl_file.fgetattr(
    location    => 'MYDIRECTORY',
    filename    => 'myfilename.ext',
    fexists     => l_file_exists,
    file_length => l_file_len,
    block_size  => l_blocksize);
  IF l_file_exists THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('File found, size=' || l_file_len);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('File not found.');
  END IF;
END;
```

To rename a file, you can use `UTL_FILE.fRename`. [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_file.htm#i1003641)

For example:

```
BEGIN
  UTL_FILE.FRENAME (
    src_location  => 'FROMDIRECTORY',
    src_filename  => 'filename.ext', 
    dest_location => 'TODIRECTORY',
    dest_filename => 'filename.ext',
    overwrite     => FALSE);
END;
```