# Listing files in a specified directory using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Is it possible to get a list of all files (and their extensions) that are stored in a specified directory using only PL/SQL? (**without** using Java procedures and other fancy things. Just plain PL/SQL code)

P.S. If it is possible, please tell me how to do that :)

Comment: Are you talking about "Oracle" directories created wit `CREATE DIRECTORY` or any arbitrary OS-level directory?

Comment: a specific "Oracle" directory

Comment: No less an authority than [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584) says it can't be done in PL/SQL, so I guess I'm going with that.  On his blog @JeffreyKemp has an interesting [solution which uses Java](http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2010/08/10/directory-file-list-in-plsql/), which may be as good as it gets.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Have to agree with you. It is not possible. Java is the way to go

Comment: it can be done. period. possible solution (although involves some "weird rights' granting") based on using **SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.searchFiles** here:
https://davidalejomarcos.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/ or here:
http://abilim.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-list-files-on-directory-from.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with plain PL/SQL but without Java. You can use a scheduler job for creating a directory listing: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16845563/802058